# PostgreSQL 8.0 - Windows Server 2008 R2 install - Service won't start

Tags: postgresql, windows-server, error-log

I am trying to install postgreSQL 8.0 on a windows server 2008 R2 machine. After the installation, the service does not start. When I try to start it manually, I get a message saying that the service started and stopped automatically. I tried running the service on a postgres account and as a local system account (in the service properties).

I don't know if this is relevant, but during the installation, I got a few alert messages about "procedural languages" and "contrib files" being installed but not activated on the database.

Every log file in pg_log is empty.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're really using 8.0? That seems awfully unlikely on Windows. If you are, that's horrible; once you get this sorted out plan an upgrade ASAP. To track this down you'll need to look at the Event Viewer logs, see what service start messages are produced.

Comment: Also, you seem to have posted this to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18138511/398670 too. Please don't cross-post like that, *especially* without linking between the two. It wastes everyone's time and splits up useful answers. I suggest deleting the other post.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using Postgres 8.0 any more - especially on windows. (Actually you shouldn't be using any version that starts with 8 on a new install - 8.4 will be taken out of support next July)

Comment: I am installing software for a client and Postgres 8.0 is the only service that has been tested with the program. We are currently upgrading to Postgres 9.2.4, but the upgrade will not be ready for a while and in the meantime, we need to install 8 on this client's windows 2008 R2 server

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling postgres, install this:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)

Reinstall postgres and see if it works then.

Comment: If they're really using 8.0, it will certainly not be built with VS 2008. At best it'll be 2005, and the installer bundles the runtime so it shouldn't generally be necessary. You're more likely to want http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=14431 .